# Corda upgrade flow/contract without shuting down the node

Tags: corda

Is there any way in corda to update the flow or contract without stopping the node?
Or is there any way to add a cordapp to a node without stopping the node?
Can jreloader do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As of Corda 4, you have to bounce the node for it to pick up any new CorDapps you've added to the CorDapps folder.

Note that because of the way Corda uses message queues, there's no risk of dropped messages while your node is down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,will Corda support this feature in the future? It means that corda can run 7*24, which makes sense in some scenarios.

Comment: There are no firms plans yet but it appears likely, yes.